# Inconsistency in the definition of electrostatic work

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work

Sorry if there this is a duplicate but I can't find anything that deals with this.

I have a point charge $q$ sitting at the origin. It takes no work for me to put it there.

Then, I bring $-q$ out from infinity and spread it around over a sphere of radius $a$ centered at the origin. It takes $dW = 1/4\pi \epsilon_0 (-q dq/a)$ to bring $-dq$ of charge in. The surface element is $dq = \sigma a^2sin\theta d\theta d\phi$. In total, we have 
$$W = \frac 1 2\int_S \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\sigma a^2sin\theta d\theta d\phi = -\frac{q\sigma a}{2\epsilon_0} = -\frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 a},$$
since $q = 4\pi a^2 \sigma$ over the sphere. This leaves me very confused, because this formula is the same as the amount of work it takes to construct the same spherical shell, but without the extra $q$ in the middle (e.g. Griffiths ex. 2.9).

I know about the inconsistencies about dealing with the work it takes to assemble point charges and charge distributions. However, I'm at a loss about where I've gone wrong above.

**How do I deal with finding the work it takes to assemble a configuration with both point charges and charge distributions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This leaves me very confused, because this formula [$W = -\dfrac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 a}$] is the same as the amount of work it takes to construct the same spherical shell, but without the extra q in the middle (e.g. Griffiths ex. 2.9).

Your value for the work done by an external force in assembling a shell of total charge $-q$ cannot be correct as it implies (negative sign) that work is done **on** the external force rather than the expectation (repulsive force between negative charges) that work is done **by** the external force.
The correct value of the amount of work done is $W =+\dfrac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 a}$

---

Having assembled these negative charges note that there is no electric field inside $r<a$ the charge distribution and so the electric potential inside the distribution is constant.
Outside $r\ge a$ the charge distribution the electric field is $E(r)=-\dfrac {q}{4\pi \epsilon_0\,r^2}$ and the electric potential is $V(r)=-\dfrac {q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0\,r}$
Now bring in the $+q$ charge from infinity to $r=a$ and the work done by a external force is $qV(r)=-\dfrac {q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0\,a}$ and then no work is done in bringing the positive charge to the centre of the negative charge distribution $r=0$.

So the total work done in assembling the charges, which is the electric potential energy of the system is $-\dfrac {q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0\,a}+\dfrac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 a}= -\dfrac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 a}$.

---

Starting with the positive charge and then assembling the negative charges requires $\displaystyle \int_0^q \int ^a_\infty \dfrac{q-Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0\,r^2}\,dr\,dQ$ of work to be done by the external force which gives $-\dfrac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 a}$ as before and in one of the intermediate steps you should recognise two terms, one for assembling the negative charges and the other when bringing in the positive charge.

---

Another way of looking at the problem is to use the energy density of an electric field $\dfrac 12 \epsilon_0 |E|^2$ and the integrate over the appropriate volume $\displaystyle \int_V \dfrac 12 \epsilon_0 |E|^2 \,dV$.
In the case of just assembling the negative charges the volume is for all $r\ge a$ and for assembling the positive and negative charges the volume is between $r=0$ and $r=a$ as in this case there is no electric field outside the negative charge distribution.

Comment: Hm. I thought I understood after the first answer, but this is like music to my ears. I understand perfectly now! So it just happens to be a coincidence that the answers have the same form.

Answer (score 0):

> This leaves me very confused, because this formula is the same as the amount of work it takes to construct the same spherical shell, but without the extra $q$ in the middle.

Not quite. Since in the first case you didn't consider *the work done to create the point charge*; as you said *it* and to bring it to the origin from infinity *for free*, you also should not consider this in the second case.You also didn't consider, in this case, *the work it took to spread out the charge over the sphere, assuming there might be any). So you should also not consider this in the second case.

**Situation 2**: Let's reverse the situation where there is no point charge and we create the sphere first. If we want to just consider a charged sphere in a vacuum (not accounting for *creating the charges* and any work it may have taken to create that configuration on the sphere *again*) then, when you dump $q$ on the sphere you get that for free. Moreover, since there are no other charges around, you also get to bring the whole sphere in from infinity *for free*. That is, $W=0$ at this point. Now, if you bring a point charge $q$ in from infinity you will see that $W$ is identical to the previous situation.

We can see that this is expected if we consider the formula for $W$ given by

$$W = \int \int \frac{\rho_1(\mathbf{r})\rho_2(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|} \ d^3r' d^3r.$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time reading your last sentence. What should I be expecting? (I may just be completely missing the point or something, but the comma placement is super weird and I don't know how I should read it.)

Comment: What is the difference between the two charge distributions $\rho_{sphere}$ and $\rho_{q}$ in each case? My argument is that there is none.

Comment: By $\rho_{\text{sphere}}$, do you mean a sphere + charge in the middle? That's what I'm talking about. And how can there be no difference? Their electric fields are different.

Comment: No each rho is the charge distribution for each the sphere and the particle separately.

Comment: I think I see the confusion now. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Alright, I think I have addressed your concern.

Comment: What's the "true" work, then? Do I account for the creation of charges, or do I not? How do I know when to account for the creation of charges?

Comment: It's up to you. If you want to account for the self energy of the particles all you have to do is add that term. But it will exist in both circumstances as well. What we usually mean by *work done* at this level is *mechanical* work done and don't consider you having to create the particles. But you can if you like.